# Hide list item by its value using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is my code and I want to hide the 'li' by its value that present in the middle using JQuery.

HTML:

```
  <ul id="tagCloud">
       <li>Item1</li>
       <li>Item2</li>
       <li>Item3</li>
       <li>Item4</li>
       <li>Item5</li>
  </ul>
```

This code output is:

```
              Item1
              Item2
              Item3
              Item4
              Item5
```

I want to hide third 'li' by its value using JQuery.

I want the output like this :

```
              Item1
              Item2
              Item4
              Item5
```

How can I do it? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `:contains` to hide anything that contains `Item3`

```
$('#tagCloud li:contains(Item3)').hide();
```

or be more specific with a filter

```
$('#tagCloud li').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === 'Item3';
}).hide();
```

or case insensitive

```
$('#tagCloud li').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().toLowerCase() === 'item3';
}).hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#tagCloud li:contains(Item3)').hide();
```